# How to put limit degree camera position rotate left,right,up, down mode using button click in three js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, trigonometry

I'm sure this question has been duplicated many times, however, I cannot find any answers to my specific problem!

I'm created the 3D canvas `WebGLRenderer`, `PerspectiveCamera`, `OrbitControls`. My camera position set 0, 10, 500. `The circular camera rotation around a central point in three js`. I used trigonometry calculation. I do not rotate mesh. I created 4 direction buttons `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, `Bottom`. example, If I clicked `left button camera to rotate left side 30 degrees`. My left and right work well. My top and bottom angle rotate not correctly. My specific problem is `1st left/right particular degree rotate after top/bottom` click rotates top/bottom direction with also object x-axis also rotate. I checked console.log x value not change. Below my code. Anybody gives the idea about this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>3D</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/projector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/crypto-js.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3587259/Code/Threejs/OrbitControls.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <button id="left" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button>
 <button id="right" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
 <button id="up" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
 <button id="down" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>
 
 <div class="row">
     <div id="drawCanvas3D"></div>
 </div>
 
 
 <script>
     var canvas3D;
  var camera3D;
  var scene3D;
  var renderer3D;
  
  var angle = 0;
     var radius = 500; 
  
  var rotateRange = 0.53;
  var rotateUpDownRange = 0.51;
  
  canvas3D = document.getElementById("drawCanvas3D");
  
  var angle = 45;
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var near = 1;
        var far = 10000;
  
  camera3D = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(angle, width / height, near, far);
  camera3D.position.set(0, 10, 500);
  
  scene3D = new THREE.Scene();
  
  if (Detector.webgl)
            renderer3D = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
        else
            renderer3D = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();

        /* Floor  */
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000, 10, 10);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x444444
        });
        var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        floor.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        floor.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        floor.castShadow = true;
        scene3D.add(floor);
  
  renderer3D.setClearColor(0x81aff9);
        renderer3D.setSize(width, height);
  canvas3D.appendChild(renderer3D.domElement);

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera3D, renderer3D.domElement);
  canvas3D.appendChild(renderer3D.domElement);
  controls.rotateSpeed = 1;
        controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
  
  
  var boxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50);    //width, height, depth
 
  var boxMaterial  = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color:0xf49542, side:THREE.DoubleSide }); 

  var squareThreeD = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial); 
  squareThreeD.position.set(0, 25, 0);   
  //squareThreeD.position.set(middlePointX, (height/2),middlePointY);  
  scene3D.add(squareThreeD);
  
  var leftMode = document.getElementById('left');
  leftMode.addEventListener('click', onLeftButtonClick);
  
  var rightMode = document.getElementById('right');
  rightMode.addEventListener('click', onRightButtonClick);
  
  var upMode = document.getElementById('up');
  upMode .addEventListener('click', onUpButtonClick);
  
  var downMode = document.getElementById('down');
  downMode .addEventListener('click', onDownButtonClick);
  
  function onLeftButtonClick(){
   
  var x = camera3D.position.x,
      y = camera3D.position.y,
      z = camera3D.position.z;
   
   camera3D.position.x = x * Math.cos(rotateRange) + z * Math.sin(rotateRange);
   camera3D.position.z = z * Math.cos(rotateRange) - x * Math.sin(rotateRange); 
  
  }
  
  function onRightButtonClick(){
   
  var x = camera3D.position.x, 
   y = camera3D.position.y, 
   z = camera3D.position.z;
   
  camera3D.position.x = x * Math.cos(rotateRange) - z * Math.sin(rotateRange);
  camera3D.position.z = z * Math.cos(rotateRange) + x * Math.sin(rotateRange); 
  
  }
  
  function onUpButtonClick(){
   console.log('up mode');
   
   document.getElementById('down').disabled = false;
   
     var  x = camera3D.position.x,
    y = camera3D.position.y,
       z = camera3D.position.z;
   
   
   
   camera3D.position.y = y * Math.cos(rotateUpDownRange) + z * Math.sin(rotateUpDownRange);
   camera3D.position.z = z * Math.cos(rotateUpDownRange) - y * Math.sin(rotateUpDownRange);
   
   console.log(camera3D.position.x, camera3D.position.y, camera3D.position.z);
    
  }
  
  function onDownButtonClick(){
   console.log('down mode');
   
   document.getElementById('up').disabled = false;
   
   
      var x = camera3D.position.x,
       y =camera3D.position.y,
       z =camera3D.position.z;
   
   camera3D.position.y = y * Math.cos(rotateUpDownRange) - z * Math.sin(rotateUpDownRange);
   camera3D.position.z = z * Math.cos(rotateUpDownRange) + y * Math.sin(rotateUpDownRange);
   
   console.log(camera3D.position.x, camera3D.position.y, camera3D.position.z);
  }
  
  
  var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(100);
        scene3D.add(axesHelper);
  
  animate3D();
  
  function animate3D()
  { 
    requestAnimationFrame(animate3D);
    controls.update();
       console.log(camera3D.position.x, camera3D.position.y, camera3D.position.z)
  
   render3D();

  }
  
  function render3D() {

        renderer3D.render(scene3D, camera3D);

    }

  
 </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to camera angle rotate 30 degree using each button click in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691445/how-to-camera-angle-rotate-30-degree-using-each-button-click-in-three-js)

Comment: ok. till I can not find the solution. I tired a lot of time. if you know, give the hints or you say what mistake in `onUpButtonClick` and `onDownButtonClick` function.@Mugen87

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set this property values to limit movements instead of doing what you have done??

```
controls.minDistance = 20.0; 
controls.maxDistance = 50.0;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI;
controls.minPolarAngle=0;
```